# Alphabetically Order HTML List with Headers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, list, html-lists

I am looking to Alphabetically order an HTML list, but after each letter, there would be a `<hr />` tag and a header, indicating the new letter list.

To revise if I wasn't clear enough, I have my list...

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#/"> john-smith/</a></li>
  <li><a href="#/"> joe-smith/</a></li>
  <li><a href="#/"> glen-smith/</a></li>
  <li><a href="#/"> daniel-smith/</a></li>
  <li><a href="#/"> johnny-smith/</a></li>
</ul>
```

And now, I wanted to have some JS code that would organise this list alphabetically, as well as give a header & line for each new letter; thus it would give an outcome somewhat similar to:

```html
<ul>
  <hr />
  <h3>D</h3>
  <li><a href="#/"> daniel-smith/</a></li>
  <hr />
  <h3>G</h3>
  <li><a href="#/"> glen-smith/</a></li>
  <hr />
  <h3>J</h3>
  <li><a href="#/"> joe-smith/</a></li>
  <li><a href="#/"> johnny-smith/</a></li>
  <li><a href="#/"> joe-smith/</a></li>
</ul>
```

I did try to do this myself, but I simply wasn't able to, I'm relatively new to JavaScript!
Thanks.

Comment: First try on your own and come here if you cannot get the approach right. Please do not ask people to just write code for you.

Comment: @SiddharthVenu I did indeed try to do this, and I wasn't able to. I couldn't find any online resources to help me, nor was I able to do it on my own.

Comment: That html structure is invalid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since putting `h3` and `hr` inside a `ul` tag is not valid, I created this style with css. Just added a `li` node with `splitter` class.

The solution has 2 steps:

1. Sort the list (using [`.sort()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp) method)
2. Create the titles.

Read the code and let me know if something not clear.

```js
var list = $('ul'),
    items = $('li', list);

// sort the list
var sortedItems = items.get().sort(function(a, b) {
  var aText = $.trim($(a).text().toUpperCase()),
      bText = $.trim($(b).text().toUpperCase());
  
   return aText.localeCompare(bText);
});

list.append(sortedItems); 

// create the titles
var lastLetter = '';
list.find('li').each(function() {
  var $this = $(this),
      text = $.trim($this.text()),
      firstLetter = text[0];

  if (firstLetter != lastLetter) {
    $this.before('<li class="splitter">' + firstLetter);
    lastLetter = firstLetter;
  }
});
```

```css
.splitter {
  border-top: 1px solid;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  list-style: none;
  padding-top: 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#/"> john-smith/</a></li>
  <li><a href="#/"> joe-smith/</a></li>
  <li><a href="#/"> glen-smith/</a></li>
  <li><a href="#/"> daniel-smith/</a></li>
  <li><a href="#/"> johnny-smith/</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: don't expect this to work cross browser, `<h3>` and `<hr>` are invalid children of `<ul>`

Comment: @charlietfl make sence.. But I just followed by his code.

Comment: Just pointing it out. Proper solution will require valid html

Comment: @MoshFeu Hey man, is it possible to wrap the "same letter items" with an outer li ? I have been trying to do it for a while but failing everytime. Can you help?

Comment: @A.Amit, What is the expected html? Can you create a jsbin for me?

Comment: @MoshFeu Hey thanks for your time. I had to do a workaround on your code above and then I've created a new question and someone has already provided a solution. But if you could provide a solution in your code then I guess it would help learn something from it. Here's the question: ```https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66444292/how-can-i-wrap-inner-divs-that-are-dynamic``` . It has the expected output at the top. If you don't mind, please check it.

Comment: The reference to the new question is good for future readers IMO. If someone else will face a similar challenge they will follow your link. (I'd recommend (1) to post the url without back-ticks for it to be clickable (2) use the "share" option to win some [badges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges#mainbar:~:text=Other%20Badges).

Answer (score 2):

You need jquery and the following code, but please be sure to remove the space from each row of the above list (before the names) :

```
var a = [];
//Loop through each row
$( "li" ).each(function( index ) {
  //populate the array with their names
  a.push($( this ).text());
});
//Alphabetically sort the array
a.sort();
//Clear the existing list
$("ul").html("");
//Start with a random character
var current_letter='1';
//loop through each row of the sorted array
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
  //if a new first character is detected, add its corresponding html
   if(a[i].charAt(0)!=current_letter){
       $("ul").append("<hr /><h3>"+a[i].charAt(0)+"</h3>");
       current_letter=a[i].charAt(0);
   }
    //add the list item to the list
    $("ul").append("<li><a href='#/'>"+a[i]+"</a></li>");
}
```