# How to replace first occurence of each letter in a list?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Let's say I have a list like this (but this will be generated so can differ)

```
<ul class="alphabet">
                    <li>2015</li>
                    <li>2019</li>
                    <li>apples</li>
                    <li>arrows</li>
                    <li>cakes</li>
                    <li>calculators</li>
                    <li>oranges</li>
                    <li>papers</li>
                    <li>parts</li>
                    <li>plums</li>
                    <li>zebras</li>
                 </ul>
```

and would like to achieve this

```
<h2>2</h2>
<ul>
<li>2015</li>
<li>2019</li>
</ul>


<h2>A</h2>
<ul>
<li>apples</li>
<li>arrows</li>
</ul>

<h2>C</h2>
<ul>
<li>cakes</li>
<li>calculators</li>
</ul>

<h2>O</h2>
<ul>
<li>oranges</li>
</ul>

<h2>P</h2>
<ul>
<li>papers</li>
<li>parts</li>
<li>plums</li>
</ul>

<h2>Z</h2>
<ul>
<li>zebras</li>
</ul>
```

under different circumstances I would use PHP to find first occurrence of a letter in a word and do replace however I need to use Javascript.

BTW: I am using easyListSplitter plugin so should I call easyListSplitter after conversion to each UL ? or is it possible to do conversion after creation of columns ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Alphabetically Order HTML List with Headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38812074/alphabetically-order-html-list-with-headers)

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's basically a simple grouping operation, and some appending to document

```js
const el = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.alphabet li'));

const grouped = el.reduce((a, b) => {
  const char = b.innerText.charAt(0).toUpperCase();
  return a.set(char, (a.get(char) || []).concat(b));
}, new Map);

const html = Array.from(grouped).forEach(([key, lis]) => {
  const h2 = document.createElement('h2');
  h2.appendChild(document.createTextNode(key));
  const ul = document.createElement('ul');
  lis.forEach(li => ul.appendChild(li));

  const div = document.createElement('div');
  div.appendChild(h2);
  div.appendChild(ul);

  document.body.appendChild(div);
});
```

```html
<ul class="alphabet">
  <li>2015</li>
  <li>2019</li>
  <li>apples</li>
  <li>arrows</li>
  <li>cakes</li>
  <li>calculators</li>
  <li>oranges</li>
  <li>papers</li>
  <li>parts</li>
  <li>plums</li>
  <li>zebras</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: thank you very much, this is what I was looking for and after some modifications I was able to implement it and easyListSplitter is not much needed as this can be achieved using CSS column-count

Answer (score 1):

Here is my approach to the problem:

```js
let listElems = document.querySelectorAll('ul.alphabet > li');
let result = document.querySelector('.result');
let lists = {};

listElems.forEach(li => {
  let firstLetter = li.innerText[0];
  firstLetter in lists ?
    lists[firstLetter].push(li):
    lists[firstLetter] = [li];
});

for(list in lists) {
  var header = document.createElement("h2");
  header.innerText = list;
  result.appendChild(header);

  var ul = document.createElement("ul");
  lists[list].map(li => ul.appendChild(li));
  result.appendChild(ul);
}
```

```html
<ul class="alphabet">
  <li>2015</li>
  <li>2019</li>
  <li>apples</li>
  <li>arrows</li>
  <li>cakes</li>
  <li>calculators</li>
  <li>oranges</li>
  <li>papers</li>
  <li>parts</li>
  <li>plums</li>
  <li>zebras</li>
</ul>
<div class="result"></div>
```