# How can I wrap inner divs that are dynamic?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been trying badly to wrap some divs with an outer div so that I can style them. But I'm unable to do so thus far.

I have this `list` div which contains some inner divs that I need to wrap. That is the inner divs which have same letters need to be bundled together. Although targeting the divs with the letters is not a good idea as they are gonna be dynamic.

This is an example of what I have been trying to achieve:

```
<div class="list-wrapper">
    <div class="el">A</div>
    <div> 
       <a>A</a>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="list-wrapper">
    <div class="el">C</div>
    <div> 
       <a>C</a>
    </div>
    <div> 
       <a>C</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Another example:

[image]

This is what I have tried so far:

```js
$(list).find('div.el').each(function(idx, item) {
  $(item).nextAll('div').wrapAll('<div class="list-wrapper"></div>')
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="list">

  <div class="el">A</div>
  <div>
    <a>A</a>
  </div>

  <div class="el">B</div>
  <div>
    <a>B</a>
  </div>

  <div class="el">C</div>
  <div>
    <a>C</a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <a>C</a>
  </div>

  <div class="el">D</div>
  <div>
    <a>D</a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <a>D</a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <a>D</a>
  </div>

  <div class="el">E</div>
  <div>
    <a>E</a>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve your goal you can use a combination of `nextUntil()` within the loop, to get the div elements between each `.el`, and `wrapAll()`. You can include `addBack()` in there to add the current `.el` in the loop in to the collection to be wrapped. Try this:

```js
$('#list').find('.el').each((i, el) => {
  $(el).nextUntil('.el').addBack().wrapAll('<div class="list-wrapper"></div>')
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 20px;
}

.list-wrapper { border: 1px solid #C00; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="list">
  <div class="el">A</div>
  <div><a>A</a></div>

  <div class="el">B</div>
  <div><a>B</a></div>

  <div class="el">C</div>
  <div><a>C</a></div>
  <div><a>C</a></div>

  <div class="el">D</div>
  <div><a>D</a></div>
  <div><a>D</a></div>
  <div><a>D</a></div>

  <div class="el">E</div>
  <div><a>E</a></div>
</div>
```

Note that `$(list)` was only working by proxy, as elements with an `id` attribute are available as properties on the `document`. It's much better practice to use a valid string selector.